# C# error CS1513 and CS1023

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I was making some kind of terminal simulator and everything was working fine until I edited something, I don't know what anymore, and I got this error

```
..\Playground\(14,38): error CS1513: } expected
..\Playground\(21,1): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
```

Can anyone tell me what happened?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MCMD{
    class INFO{
        static string LANG="CSharp";
        static string STAT="A";
        static string VERS="0.0.1.0";
    }
    class TERMINAL{
        static void IFunc(string question){
            private string lang=System.MCMD.INFO.LANG;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args){
            Console.Write(IFunc());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are missing a } or having additional }. :)

Comment: That's coz the class is not properly defined. It says that } is missing. Check open and close curly brace pairs.

Comment: @Dileep Yeah that's the thing, I checked that. You can check my code.

Comment: In future please put your code in the question itself.

Comment: you need to add reference for your "System.MCMD"

Comment: @Dileep I'll try

Comment: `private string lang= ... ` drop the `private` it's inside a method body.

Comment: You've a stray `System.` in there.

Comment: @ClickRick please explain

Comment: `string lang=MCMD.INFO.LANG;` that's how `lang`  should be declared. Going back to c# syntax tutorial should help.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya come on I know I'm a starter and that I have to learn a lot, but you could have been nicer, like: if you wanna learn more about this, you could try a c# syntax tutorial

Comment: I didn't mean to be rude. All I wanted to say was understanding from reading and experimenting is better then getting ready made answers.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya yeah you're right. I did, but not enough obviously

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`private` is not a valid modifier for local variables as you have in `IFunc`, so you need to remove it. You also need to remove `System` from the fully-qualified name of `INFO.LANG`.

```
static void IFunc(string question){
    string lang=MCMD.INFO.LANG;
}
```

You also need to provide a string argument when calling `IFunc` from main:

```
static void Main(string[] args){
    Console.Write(IFunc("some string"));
}
```